# search by multiple variants in datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, datatables

I have datatable with more columns. Second column contains MAC address in format AABBCCDDEEFF. I want to try search all variants/formats of MAC addresses eg.

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
AABBCCDDEEFF
AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF
```

I don't want use hidden columns with every variant.
I don't want use cell atrib. for all variants data-search.

I tried make this example, but it is blinking with every search input change and not reflect search by any other column.

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/ep7d6as0/134
Thank you for help.

Comment: your fiddle works fine for me. What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem then the constant flickering is what you want to address? If so I'd use lodash's debounce like this:

```
$('#example_filter input').keyup(function() {
  var search = this.value.replace(/[:-]/g, '');
  _.debounce(table.search(
    jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.mac(search)
  ).draw(), 500)
});
```

Hope that helps. Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/ep7d6as0/186/).